# How to prevent footer view to not moving up when Keyboard open in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to prevent the footer view from not moving up when Keyboard open in Jetpack compose. I am looking for the solution without windowSoftInputMode properties as it is conflicting with BringViewRequester property for textfield.

Comment: Kindly provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.